# How to properly get a Collection out of an Entity using getProperty()

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When I put an ArrayList into an Entity using setUnindexedProperty(), how does it come back out?

I'm doing this:

```
Collection<Key> keys = (Collection<Key>) entity.getProperty(propName);
```

And I get this warning:

```
 warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.util.Collection<com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key>
    Collection<Key> keys = (Collection<Key>) entity.getProperty(propName);
```

Is this the best I can do?  Is there at least a way to get rid of the warning?

UPDATE: I do not get this warning on other entity.getProperty() calls that return an object that I downcast to, say a String or a Blob.

Comment: Is it possible that your import of `Key` is to something other than `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key`? Every so often Eclipse offers up the wrong imports.

Comment: No, I am not using Eclipse, so I didn't accidentally import some other library.

Answer (score 1):

entity.getProperty() returns an Object. It has no way of knowing what you're actually putting in or getting out, so it's always going to warn you unless you @SuppressWarnings. If you aren't comfortable doing it this way you have to use something like Objectify/Twig/JDO instead of the native datastore.

Comment: That can't be it because I have other places where I use getProperty(), cast the result down to, say, a String or Blob, and I do *not* get a warning.

Comment: Look at the api. getProperty returns an Object. If you cast an Object to anything you get a warning about an unchecked cast. That's the way java works.

Comment: Well, no.  As I said in the previous comment, in other places I am casting the Object to something else and I am *not* getting the warning.  I'm only getting it when casting to Collection<Key>.

Comment: where is it not giving you the warning? There must be some reason why the compiler knows that the other one is safe.

Comment: As I said in the update, it is not giving me the warning when I cast any other type that comes out of an entity.getProperty(), such as a String or a Blob.

Comment: My assumption is that you can safely cast to a String because calling object.toString() is defined for all objects. Not sure why this would work for a Blob, but you should definitely expect this for any other object where there isn't a "safe" path for casting.

Comment: Casting to a string does not call toString().  Please stop making stuff up when you don't know what you are talking about; it does not help the discussion.  I want to hear from someone who actually knows something about this question.

Comment: Yes, I'm speculating to why you aren't getting warnings for String or Blob based on very little information from you. I already explained that unless the vm KNOWS that the object you are casting to is valid it will throw that warning. I tried it myself and don't get warnings about casting to Strings which I can only assume means the VM will call toString on the object (since that's completely valid). I don't believe that you can cast to a Blob without some hint to the VM that your object is in fact a blob, but you haven't shown code where that works. It really should not.

Comment: (1) It is *not* valid for the VM to call toString() on an object in lieu of *casting* it to a String.  (2) The code where it casts to a Blob looks like this: (Blob) entity.getProperty(prop); what did you think it would look like?  You are guessing which is a waste of my time; please stop.

Comment: Ok. I'm wrong. I researched it because I thought I knew the answer but clearly didn't after trying some things, so I was curious. The reason is that you (usually) only get this warning when casting to a parameterized type (i.e. a generic or collection with a generic type). See: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ001 under "What is an "unchecked" warning?" So we both learned something.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following annotation to ignore the unchecked cast warning.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

But that assumes that you want to suppress the warnings rather than to fix the issue that it complained about.

Comment: And how exactly should I "fix" the issue?